# Show fiberwise lipschtiz then solve the ODE

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

Solve the ODE (course I am taking is Analysis II)

$\frac{dx}{dt}=(x+t)t$, $\forall t\in [0,1]$, $x(0)=0$

### My attempt

First we have to show fiberwise lipshitz. To show that $V(t,x(t))$ satisfies fiberwise lipshitz it must satisfy:
$$|V(y,x(t)-V(t,x'(t)| \leq L_t|x-x'|$$ such that $L_t \geq 0$ and $x \neq x'$ 
So

$$|(x+t)t-(x'+t)t| \leq L_t|x-x'|=(xt+t^2)-(tx'+t^2)| \leq L_t|x-x'|$$
$$\frac{|(xt+t^2)-(tx'+t^2)|}{|x-x'|} \leq L_t$$

Not sure where to go from here..

anyways...

$\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}=V(x(t),t)=(x+t)$

Now..

$\phi_v^1(x,t)=x(0)+\int_{0}^{t}(x+t)t dt= (t^3/3)+(t^2x/2)$ s.t $x(0)=0$.

converges to a unique $x(t):[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ since it is fiberwise Lip.

Applying $\phi_V$ to calculate $\phi^n_V$:

$\phi_v^2(x,t)=+\int_{0}^{t} (t^3x/2)+(t^4/3)+t^2 dt= (t^4x/8 +t^5/15+t^3/3$

...

Comment: How did you get this $\int_0^t xt\,dt=t^2x/2$? Do you assume $x$ to be constant?